# In John 19:17 did author incorrectly attribute word Golgotha from Hebrew transliteration or correctly from Aramaic? (Differing English Translations)

Tags: greek, hebrew, john, translation-philosophy, aramaic

An English Bible translation which attributes it as Hebrew:

> John 19:17, KJV: And he bearing his cross went forth into a place called the place of a skull, which is called in the **Hebrew** Golgotha:

As Aramaic:

> John 19:17, ESV: and he went out, bearing his own cross, to the place called The Place of a Skull, which in **Aramaic** is called Golgotha.

Both interprations could not be correct, and the greek seems to imply the author was attributing the word as Hebrew. Which is correct and why?

Comment: Related: [Does "Hebrew" refer to the language or the language family?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11677/does-hebrew-refer-to-the-language-or-the-language-family)

Answer (score 1):

In the Greek Septuagint the word **Σῠριστί** (*Syrist*i, viz. "Syriac") is used to indicate Aramaic (e.g. 4 Kingdoms/2 Kings 18:26, Isaiah 36:11, Daniel 2:4).  I don't believe the word appears anywhere in the New Testament.

A different Greek word is used to mean "Hebrew":  **Ἑβραϊστί** (*Ebraisti*).

The word in John 19:17 is the latter, Ἑβραϊστί ("Hebrew"), and not Σῠριστί ("Aramaic").

Either the word Σῠριστί fell completely out of usage by the time of the New Testament, which seems unlikely; or perhaps the words quoted are so related the ESV translators felt it made no difference.

Comment: It would seem then that John was in-correct. As Golgotha is a Aramaic translation, not Hebrew.

Comment: @taylor, what is the Hebrew version of "Golgotha"?

Comment: While Im not going to say I have the authority to definitively say it is in-correct, the articles I have read say that the greek was an aramaic transliteration, not hebrew. The Hebrew is Gulgoleth. Aramaic is Gulgaltha.